# Using classes from different autoloaders

Tags: php, laravel, autoloader, xenforo

I'm trying to integrate a Laravel app with Xenforo. The easiest way of doing this seems to be syncing user's creation, login, logout events.

So, whenever a user logs out from Xenforo, for example, I'd like to trigger Laravel's `Auth::logout`.

Xenforo was installed in Laravels `public/forum` folder.

Xenforo's logout action is performed at `public/forum/src/XF/Pub/Controller/Logout.php`:

```
namespace XF\Pub\Controller;

use XF\Mvc\ParameterBag;
use XF\Mvc\Reply\AbstractReply;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; // ===========> WONT WORK

class Logout extends AbstractController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->assertValidCsrfToken($this->filter('t', 'str'));

        /** @var \XF\ControllerPlugin\Login $loginPlugin */
        $loginPlugin = $this->plugin('XF:Login');
        $loginPlugin->logoutVisitor();
        Auth::logout(); // =========================> WONT WORK

        return $this->redirect($this->buildLink('index'));
    }

    (...)
}
```

I guess its due Xenforo not knowing about this class because its autoload doesnt know about it.

1. Is there a way to make Xenforo, which has its own autoloader, also consider Laravels autoloader?
2. If not how can I add this class into Xenforos autoloader?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you *could*, it would likely be messy and could introduce bugs that you wouldn't have considered. The cleanest approach would be setting up an API endpoint in Laravel that you can make a request to from within your Xenforo logout controller, or an artisan command that the controller calls to logout the given user. This way, you prevent having to bootstrap the framework from within another framework, and you keep the two nicely separated.

Comment: Shouldn't artisan commands be only used for development / maintenance purposes? Is a good practice to use it for runtime applications stuff? Thanks.

Comment: That's up to you to decide. Personally I would rather go the API endpoint route, just be sure to require authentication for it.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the [official composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) on how to include additional autoloaders in.

**EDIT:**

I am going to rephrase my answer; you shouldn't try to load Laravel into Xenforo because of possible third-party library version issues, duplicate helper methods (if Xenforo has any), various other issues might occur, you are better off with using Laravel as `endpoint` and making `REST` calls for login, logout, etc. Exactly what @samrap mentioned.

My question is why would you use Xenforo, is it mandatory to use it to achieve whatever you are trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to add a forum (xenforo) in my site. But I dont want to force the user to login/logout/register twice.

Comment: Any particular reason why u prefer xenforo instead of some forum made to work with Laravel?